# How to create an executable file from my project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, executable

I have a project in eclipse which uses part of another java project for changing some variables. I need to create an executable file from my project but all instructions that I try doesn't work.

I created a runnable jar file by exporting my project but the jar file doesn't run. Then I used the launch4j to create an ".exe" file from the jar file but when I click one the .exe file instead of running, it unzips to a folder. 
just in case if it is an important point, I am using mac os.

Comment: why don't you use the jar file as an external library? why you want to run the jar file?

Comment: is your jar file a runnable jar file ?

Comment: You are running an EXE on a Mac? Why did you think that would work?

Comment: Unfortunately EXE files won't work on macOS since it's windows specific file extention.

Comment: My jar file is runnable. I just need to be able to run my java project without its source code. I thought it would be possible with a jar or exe file. is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse;

[image]
[image]

Click Next and give a destination

[image]

Comment: hi, sorry but the images you uploaded are not visible for me.

Comment: Can you see it now ?

Comment: unfortunately not.